# Why SQLAlchemy won't commit changes?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I've done this so many times before successfully but all of the sudden I can't seem
to make it work. I'm creating tables in my MySQL database using Flask SQLAlchemy as a middleman.
Also using `pymysql` adapter.

Can you please check my "plumbing" is correct ?

my **init**.py :

```
import werkzeug
werkzeug.cached_property = werkzeug.utils.cached_property
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from .config import DevConfig

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()

def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(DevConfig)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    from .flask_app import users_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)

    @app.shell_context_processor
    def ctx():
        return {'app': app, 'db': db}

    return app
```

models.py:

```
from project import db, bcrypt


class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    ...
    ...
```

config.py:

```
import os


class BaseConfig:
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://mark:supersecret@localhost/database1?charset=utf8mb4'   #  the "?charset" thingy is there to avoid encoding warnings from SQLAlchemy
    SECRET_KEY = 'pythonrocks'

class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True

class ProdConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = False
```

interpreter:

```
Instance: /home/mark/project/instance
In [1]: db                                                                                                                                            
Out[1]: <SQLAlchemy engine=mysql+pymysql://mark:***@localhost/database1?charset=utf8mb4>

In [2]: db.create_all()                                                                                                                               

In [3]: db.session.commit()
```

I get no error output. The tables are just not being created on commit.

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I check what's causing this ? The dev server is running.

Comment: From what you've included in your question, it doesn't seem like you're importing your models in any location before issuing `create_all()` - SQLAlchemy doesn't know about your model. Import it first, then call `create_all()`

Comment: @MatsLindh  What a rookie mistake ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You're not importing your models before calling `db.create_all()` - SQLAlchemy simply doesn't know about your models - and thus can't create the tables.

Import it first, then call `db.create_all()` and `db.session.commit()`.